# Installer that can deploy a raw disk image to a bare metal server?

Tags: system-installation

I would like to automate deployment of bare-metal servers based on disk images. These disk images are raw dumps, like you would get with `dd`.

The problem is that I can't find an installer that can do the simple task of getting the raw image onto disk.

Basically I want something like Clonezilla, but capable of using raw images. (Clonezilla has it's own format for images and can't handle anything else. I did look for a way to turn a raw image into a Clonezilla image, but it's definitely non-trivial and there's nothing ready made.)

A few more details, though they don't make much difference to the question:

- Images are prepared with HashiCorp Packer
- The OS being installed is Ubuntu Server
- On first boot a bunch of scripts will take care of finishing up the installation (changing machine identity, growing partitions, etc). This is done with the cloud-init facilities built into Ubuntu.